# Decoding JSON objects and JSON array inside a JSONObject

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am currently working on a PHP/JavaScript/jQuery project where PHP returns some JSON encoded data to a web page via an ajax request.

The JSON data contains multiple objects and an array but I can't see how to get process the data.

Below is how the JSON is created in PHP

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result)
{
    $data = array();
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $data[] = $myrow['VersionName'];
    }

    $returnArray["RESULT"] = HelperClass::generateResponseArray(HTTPResponseCodes::OK, true, null, false);
    $returnArray["DATA"] = $data;
    return json_encode($returnArray);

}
```

The `generateResponseArray` function looks like the following:

```
public static function generateResponseArray($httpStatusCode, $wasActionSuccessful, $message,
                $jsonEncodeArray = true)
{
    $response = array();
    $response["HTTPStatusCode"] = $httpStatusCode;
    $response["actionSuccessful"] = $wasActionSuccessful;
    $response["Message"] = $message;
    if ($jsonEncodeArray)
    {
        return json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Below is how I am trying to decode the JSON via JavaScript.

```
function getVersions()
{
    $.post("../Middleware/CrashManagement.php",
        {
           type: "GetVersions",
           appID: getParameterValue("id")
        },
        function (result)
        {
           var obj = JSON.parse(result);
           var resultData = JSON.parse(obj.RESULT);
           if (resultData.actionSuccessful === true)
           {
               alert("hello");
           }
        }
     )
}
```

Chrome's not giving me any pointers as to where the problem is, it just says unexpected end of input at my html start tag for some reason, but it something to do with this function as if I remove chrome no longer reports this error.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `getJSON` rather than `post`? Also, I'm pretty sure all jQuery's Ajax functions return parsed data so you should just be able to `result.actionSuccessful` to get at the value once the data has been returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the PHP stuff is ok.

But you are parsing the returned data twice and that is not necessary.

```
function getVersions() {
    $.post("../Middleware/CrashManagement.php",
        { type: "GetVersions", appID: getParameterValue("id") },
        function (result) {
           // parse returned json string into a json object
           var obj = $.parseJSON(result);

           // No need to reparse this as its already done above
           //var resultData = JSON.parse(obj.RESULT);

           var resultData = obj.RESULT;
           if (resultData.actionSuccessful === true) {
               alert("hello");
           }
        })
}
```

If your prefered browser is Chrome, can I suggest that you get familiar with the [Chrome javascript debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

This would have shown you where you were going wrong in a second.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking you'd have to separately decode each object/array contained within the JSON. I do know about the Chrome debugger but it didn't give any error apart from what I had put in my question.